# Facebook Pixel fbq('track') isn't working in production

Tags: reactjs, facebook-pixel

I'm injecting the pixel script in the `<Head />` and trying to use the `fbq("track")` function in a contact form's `onSubmit` handler. A dumbed down version of the handler:

```
const handleSubmit = async e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    // send form data to server, if successful, proceed...
    window.fbq("track", "Contact");
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error
  }
};
```

In development, everything looks as expected: the Facebook Pixel Helper shows that the "Contact" event was successfully tracked.

However, in production, that event doesn't get tracked. The Pixel Helper registers a "Button Click Automatically Detected," but the explicit "Contact" event is not tracked. *Edit: The title of my question may be a bit of a misnomer as the `fbq("track", "PageView")` call in the `<Head />` is working normally.*

No errors, it simply doesn't seem like it's firing.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**Solved.**

Perhaps a bit more code context was needed for the issue. I still don't exactly know *why* this fix worked, but in case anybody stumbles across this in the future, here's what did it for me...

Additional context, the form data was posted to the server via `fetch()` and `window.fbq("track")` was chained into a `.then()` callback like so:

```
const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await fetch("/contact", {options})
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          if (json.success) {
            // handle success
            window.fbq("track", "Contact");
          } 
        });
    } catch (error) {
      // handle error
    }
  };
```

The solution was simply to move the `fbq()` out of the callback:

```
const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await fetch("/contact", {options})
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          if (json.success) {
            // handle success
            } 
        });
    } catch (error) {
      // handle error
      return;
    }
    window.fbq("track", "Contact");
  };
```